Println!() and print!() function confusion in Rust
when I run
fn main() {
    println!("Guess the Number!!!!!");
    print!("please Enter your Guess :-");
    let mut guess = String::new();
    // taking input
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("failed to readline");
    // parsing into Integer

    println!("you Guessed: {guess}");
}

it gives out:
Guess the Number!!!!!
213
please Enter your Guess :-you Guessed: 213

but in the second code block:
fn main() {
    println!("Guess the Number!!!!!");
    println!("please Enter your Guess :-");
    let mut guess = String::new();
    // taking input
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("failed to readline");
    // parsing into Integer

    println!("you Guessed: {guess}");
}

it gives out:
Guess the Number!!!!!
please Enter your Guess :-
213
you Guessed: 213

why in first case the please enter your guess is running after input of the number
I was expecting both the cases must not  make a difference in the out or the control flow of the statement

This happens because standard output is line buffered, so it will only actually send the entire buffer at the end of the line. You can manually flush it to send the partial data immediatly.

Because buffering: print! and println! write to stdout, stdout is line-buffered, so data written to stdout is kept in a buffer until it exceeds the buffer size or contains a newline.
println! always writes out a newline, so it always gets flushed out to the OS. print! does not, so the content stays in the buffer until an event forces it out.
So in the first case, "please Enter your Guess :-" is in the output buffer as the program waits for your input, and is only flushed out when the last line of the program runs.
You can flush the stream in order to force the data out.
